# JavaScript error because of multiple tabs

Tags: javascript

I have deployed my website twice on IIS (so I have different links). Now when I open both the links simultaneously in different tabs of same browser and get logged in to both the links, the link to which I logged first stopped working and throwed the following JavaScript error on any button click:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at
>   HTMLDivElement.

If I only open one link at a time then everything works fine. Why I'm getting the error only when both links are opened simultaneously ?

Comment: post the js code so we can take a better look at why it happens.

Comment: `function isMobileView() {

        if (sessionStorage.desktop) 
            return false;
        else if (localStorage.mobile) 
            return true;

        
        var mobile = ['iphone', 'ipad', 'android', 'blackberry', 'nokia', 'opera mini', 'windows mobile', 'windows phone', 'iemobile'];
        for (var i in mobile) if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(mobile[i].toLowerCase()) > 0) return true;
        return false;
    }`

This is the code where i get exception

Comment: @SujitAgarwal can you kindly tell me the issue, if you have any idea. I get the exception at "indexOf".